# Procurar palavra na primeira coluna de array

Tags: c#, .net, array, array-multidimensional, contains

Como faço para procurar por uma palavra em todas as linhas, mas apenas na primeira coluna de um *array* que irá sempre aumentar de tamanho?

```
string[,] array = new string[1,6]{{"texto","","","","",""}};

    if(array[array.Length, 0].Contains("texto")){
                //Encontrou palavra
        }
```

Tentei assim, mas não deu certo.

Comment: Estou fechando porque pela resposta postada só o autor poderia responder a pergunta. Havia requisitos não estabelecidos de forma clara na pergunta.

Comment: Estou sentido aqui nesse forum que cheguei a poucos dias, um ar meio competitivo, cara eu não quero pontos de reputação ou algo assim, se quiser pode até excluir a pergunta, eu só tinha uma dúvida, e consegui resolver meu problema com um for, e foi só depois de ver o exemplo inclusive da sua resposta que me veio a ideia de usar um for de maneira mais simples. Agradeço a todos pela ajuda.

Comment: A questão não é essa, é que a pergunta não está clara, só você poderia ter respondido do jeito que você queria, a resposta portando não está clara, e respostas que não estão claras precisam ser fechadas, até porque a pessoa que for ler isso depois e for tentar aprender com isso vai pode ficar confuso porque o que está escrito é diferente do que tinha que ser respondido. Se quiser falar com mais propriedade sobre o funcionamento do site pode fazer o [tour] e ver os detalhes na [help]. Reforço o aviso acima sobre [ask].Assim evita confusões e dificuldades p/ q as pessoas deem respostas adequadas

Comment: O icaro conseguiu dar uma resposta adequada, e a sua também pode se dizer que é adequada, pois o que pode ser adequado para minha situação é diferente para o que poderia ser adequado para a situação de outro.

Comment: Quanto a competitividade você tem razão que algumas pessoas levam isso ai extremo. Eu recebi um negativo na resposta sem saber porque. Ela está completa e o mais correta possível. Inclusive atualizei para ficar de acordo com sua resposta. Eu não negativei a sua, até porque ela não está errada, no máximo não funciona em todas situações, mas isso é algo que você deve decidir se quer assim ou não, minha resposta serve para outras pessoas que queira o mais correto. Eu só negativei a resposta errada, afinal ela não faz o desejado, dá erro,e mostrei em comentário porque a minha funciona corretamente

Comment: A resposta do ícaro está bem errada, para qualquer caso, a resposta dele dá erro fácil, tem problemas de performance, não responde o que você queria de fato, entre outras pequenas coisas que são mais subjetivas. A sua está correta, desde que se garanta que o *array* foi criado dentro da normalidade, se ele foi criado com faixa fora do normal a sua dá erro também, mas tudo bem, como isso é raro não vou considerar que a sua está errada. A minha faz tudo o que está na pergunta e até mais. Se não era exatamente o que você queria é porque a pergunta não está clara quanto a isso. Faltam requisitos.

Comment: Então é isso que estou dizendo, na minha situação a melhor seria a que eu fiz, mas talvez para outro seja a que você fez. Quanto ao -1 não fui eu, eu nem sabia que existia isso até ler seu comentário ali kkkkkkk

Comment: Não se preocupe que eu sei que não foi você, você nem tem privilégio de negativar ainda. Só para confirmar o que eu disse sobre a resposta do ícaro: https://dotnetfiddle.net/ueBlhi

Answer (score 4):

Como é um algoritmo um pouco mais complexo que exige algumas linhas acho mais interessante fazer um método que trate isso. Um método de extensão torna o uso mais natural. Mas se não deseja basta extrair a lógica interna. Mas criar abstrações faz parte do aprendizado.

Para pegar o tamanho da dimensão o correto é pegar o início da faixa e o fim dela através dos métodos `GetLowerBound()` e `GetUpperBound()`. Pode funcionar com `GetLength()` na maioria dos casos, mas não em todos. Eu prefiro fazer certo sempre. Mesmo que seja um exercício. Na verdade é até mais importante, quando está aprendendo é melhor aprender certo. Não basta funcionar. Mesmo que não queria usar isso, só atente que usar apenas `Length` não pega o tamanho da dimensão.

```
using static System.Console;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var array = new string[1, 6] {{"texto", "", "", "", "", ""}};
        if (array.ContainsInFirstCol("texto")) WriteLine("achou");        
    }
}

public static class ArrayExt {
    public static bool ContainsInFirstCol(this string[,] array, string search) {
        for (int row = array.GetLowerBound(0); row <= array.GetUpperBound(0); row++) {
            if (array[row, 0].Contains(search)) return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/rctMC4). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/AVRqwl). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Array/ContainsString.cs).

Note que um *array* não pode aumentar de tamanho. A resposta do AP foi feita de tal forma que o código não pode ser usado em outros pontos onde um outro *array* seja declarado com outro tamanho.

Comment: Complicou muito :/

Comment: @ÍcaroDantas Não entendi. Até tinha um erro mesmo porque eu fiz o inverso do que a pergunta pedia. Mas pelo menos eu fiz um `Contains` conforme foi pedido, fiz genérico, como extensão para ficar natural, e fiz só na primeira coluna, conforme foi especificado (sem perder tempo em olhar o *array* todo), não dá erro de fora da faixa, e funciona com *array* com faixas fora do padrão. Talvez eu tenha tomado um -1 por ter feito pegar a primeira linha e não a primeira coluna como o pedido, agora está correto e quem deu o negativo poderia retirá-lo, ou explicar o que tem errado.

Answer (score 3):

```
for(int i = 0; i <  array.GetLength (0); i++){
            if (array [i, 0].Contains ("Texto")) {
                Debug.Log ("achou");
}
```

Consegui assim.

Comment: Pode tirar esse Contains po, bota só assim: `if (array [i, 0] == "Texto")`

Comment: Na verdade depende do que você quer, porque contains por exemplo se você buscar por banan, ele vai encontrar banana, agora == "banana" se você pesquisar banan, ele vai retornar null.

Comment: Entendi agora o/! Até editei minha resposta ;)

Answer (score -1):

Primeiro isso aqui está errado: `string array[,] = new string[1,6]{{"texto","","","","",""}};`
Deveria ser: `string[,] array = new string[1, 6] { { "texto", "", "", "", "", "" } };`

Aqui a função que você procura:

```
public static int IndexOfStringInArrayOfStrings(string[,] arrayDeStrings, string stringQueVocêProcura, int colunaEmQueAFunçãoDeveProcurar)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayDeStrings.Length; i++) // Aqui eu percorro todas as linhas.
    {
        if (arrayDeStrings[i, colunaEmQueAFunçãoDeveProcurar].Contains(stringQueVocêProcura)) // Aqui eu checo se na célula[i, j] têm a string que você procura.
        {
            return i; // Caso tenha a string, imediatamente a função se encerra e retorna sua posição. 0 = Primeira linha do texto.
        }
    }
    return -1; // Se chegar até o fim, certamente não encontrou nada.
}
```